# How to display an image from a dropdown menu selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here, I have the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("value") == "Oone") {
        $(".box").hide();
        $(".red").show();
      }
      if ($(this).attr("value") == "Otwo") {
        $(".box").hide();
        $(".green").show();
      }
      if ($(this).attr("value") == "Othree") {
        $(".box").hide();
        $(".blue").show();
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

```css
    .box {
      padding: 20px;
      display: none;
      margin-top: 20px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .red {
      background: #ff0000;
    }
    .green {
      background: #00ff00;
    }
    .blue {
      background: #0000ff;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select>
    <option style="display: none;">Choose Color</option>
    <option value="Oone">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Otwo">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Othree">Option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red option</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
```

(I got this from an external source) but what happens is when someone selects Option 1, 2 or 3 it will create a red, green or blue box with some text in it. I was wondering how to implement images into this. So when someone selects Option 1 an image will appear and when they select Option 2 (the other image will hide) and a different image will appear.

I have been trying to get it to work by adding an image by creating a new class under css and when someone selects option 1 it will make it appear however, that did not work. - Thanks

Comment: Put an image in your `.box`s? `<div class="red box"><img src="red_image.bla" ></div>`

Comment: Ahh right. But I would want a different picture for each option? Do you mean I could put my image under `border: 1px solid #000`?

Comment: You could use a background image for the boxes.

Comment: Ahh right, ok. Well could I create a new `$(".pic").show();` and then have a new class in the css called `.pic`? Or would I just include it into the `.box`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the images you want to display inside the respective `<div>`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("value") == "Oone") {
        $(".box").hide();
        $(".red").show();
      }
      if ($(this).attr("value") == "Otwo") {
        $(".box").hide();
        $(".green").show();
      }
      if ($(this).attr("value") == "Othree") {
        $(".box").hide();
        $(".blue").show();
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

```css
.box {
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.box img {
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}
.red {
  background: #ff0000;
}
.green {
  background: #00ff00;
}
.blue {
  background: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select>
    <option style="display: none;">Choose Color</option>
    <option value="Oone">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Otwo">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Othree">Option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red option</strong> so i am here
  <img src="http://i46.tinypic.com/2epim8j.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here
  <img src="http://i49.tinypic.com/28vepvr.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here
  <img src="http://i50.tinypic.com/f0ud01.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh right, so it is fairly simple. So if I wanted to add more content to it such as text and other images, I could just add it inside the div? - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just have different images in different class, based on the selection you can show the class.

```
.red {
  background-image:"img1.png";
}
.green {
  background-image:"img2.png";
}
.blue {
  background-image:"img3.png";
}
```

NOw the script will be as you expected

```
 $("select").change(function() {
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("value") == "Oone") {
        $(".box").hide();
        $(".red").show();
      }
      if ($(this).attr("value") == "Otwo") {
        $(".box").hide();
        $(".green").show();
      }
      if ($(this).attr("value") == "Othree") {
        $(".box").hide();
        $(".blue").show();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Ahhh, ok. So I could either put it in the `<div>` or I can put it in this part of the HTML? (Are they the same thing)?

Comment: What i gave you is a CSS solution. @TJ given HTML solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can put images in your boxes the normal way, using the `img` element. They will be hidden as long as the `.box` is hidden. You could also simplify your js code a bit, if you changed the `value` property of your `options` to the corresponding css class of your `.box`'s:

```
<div>
  <select>
    <option style="display: none;">Choose Color</option>
    <option value="red">Option 1</option>
    <option value="green">Option 2</option>
    <option value="blue">Option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="red box">
    You have selected <strong>red option</strong> so i am here
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="green box">
    You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
<div class="blue box">
    You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
```

Here is the js:

```
$("select").change(function() {
  $('.box').hide();
  $('.' + $(':selected', this).attr('value')).show();
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9on6a1vk/).